Compare residuals of B-cubic spline fit of two groups
I have two groups, A and B.
I perform multiple measurements of the response, amplitude versus time. For the group A and the group B. The response is non-linear; therefore, I perform a Cubic B-spline fit using scipy splrep and knots.
So I have a

Cubic B-spline fit for group A
Cubic B-spline fit for group B

I would like to know if the Cubic B-spline fit for group A equals the Cubic B-spline fit for group B.
Currently, I calculate the residuals; I have residuals for Group A and residuals for Group B, and I perform a non-parametric test, the Whitney U test.
Is this correct?

For clarification, here is some extra information:

The main idea is to perform statistical analysis to see if the difference I see is statistically significant. I have made a scatter plot together with the two spline fits. There is a difference; however, this is a small visual, but some statistics are needed to make final conclusions.

I perform a non-parametric test, the Whitney U test and the residuals of the two different groups, i.e. two different types of a population. Given the two groups are sample from a different population I have some doubt about using the residuals of the two groups is the way to go.

Group A is a non-linear system, and group B is a non-linear system, Sb. We apply an input signal X to System Sa, and the same signal X to System B. We apply this signal m times (X1, X2, X3, ... X4). Next, We fit a cubic B-spline with given knots. We get a fit for System Sa and System Sb. If we plot both fits on the scatter plot, we see a difference in fit, however small. We like to see if there is a significant difference.

We can estimate parameters (features) such as peak amplitude, rise time, fall time, ..., for each fit. Is the way to perform statistics here (on the features) to see if there is a statistically significant difference in response, considering the sample size?



Fit a model like y ~ group + spline(x) + group x spline(x) and do a chunk test on the interaction terms.  This exactly tests for the shape/slope of x being the same across the groups.  For example in the R rms package, assuming Y is continuous and residuals have a normal distribution with constant variance:
require(rms)
f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x, 4) * group)
anova(f)

Where rcs stands for restricted cubic spline (natural spline) here with 4 default knots.  You’ll get all the multiple degree of freedom F tests you need from anova.

Harell, thanks for the response. However, I am not sure about your proposal given my problem. I added some extra information to my post.

What I provided exactly solves your problem by answering the general multiple-parameter question of whether the two curves differ in shapes or slopes.  If you want to also add in whether they different in vertical locations you can add the group main effect to the chunk test (which is also provided by rms anova).

It's really going to depend on exactly what you mean by "equals" but four ideas that spring to mind are

the distance between the two curves;

A quantile-quantile plot of the two curves;

Scatterplots of the fitted values of the two curve;

Taking the absolute value of the differences and seeing how far it is from 0 (or looking at each difference).


There are a few methods for the first and I am not an expert, so I won't recommend anything specific. But they would allow statistical tests to compare them.
Quantile quantile plots take a little getting used to, but can be very useful for this kind of exploration.
A scatterplot of the predicted values lets you see things kind of directly.

thanks for the feedback. I added some extra information. I made a scatterplot with the fit; I see a small difference; however, some statistics are needed to see if this difference is significant. Given that the two groups are samples from different populations, I doubt that comparing residuals is the correct way to move forward.

Why do you want to see if the difference is significant?

@ Peter Flom. I would like to see if there is a significant difference between the cubic B-spline fit (fit A) for group B and the cubic B-spline fit (fit B) for group B. A and B are non-linear systems, Sa and Sb.  Both systems get the same input signal X. However, both non-linear systems, Sa and Sb, are different (given the groups are different). I like to see if the response to input X is the same.

But why is significant key here? I would be more concerned with the size of the difference. Whether that size is significant is a function of sample size.

We can estimate parameters (features) such as peak amplitude, rise time, fall time, ... for each fit. Is the way to perform here statistics to see if there is a statistically significant difference, considering the sample size?
